# How to implement a general set randomizer?

Tags: javascript

Let us suppose that I intend to implement a randomization functionality, like this:

```
function Randomizer() {
    //Get random member name of object
    Object.prototype.getRandomKey = function() {
        var keys = Object.keys(this);
        return keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length)];
    };
    //Get random member value of object
    Object.prototype.getRandomElement = function() {
        return this[this.getRandomKey()];
    };
    //Get random index of array
    Array.prototype.getRandomKey = function() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length);
    };
    //Get random element of array
    Array.prototype.getRandomElement = function() {
        return this[this.getRandomKey()];
    };
    //Get random return key of function result
    Function.prototype.getRandomKey = function() {
        var result = this.apply(this, arguments);
        return result && result.getRandomKey();
    };
    //Get random return member of function result
    Function.prototype.getRandomElement = function() {
        var result = this.apply(this, arguments);
        return result && result.getRandomElement(result.getRandomKey());
    };
    //Get random element name of what if supported
    Randomizer.getRandomKey = function(what) {
        if ((!what) || (["undefined", "number", "boolean"].indexOf(typeof what) >= 0)) {
            //unsupported
        } else if (typeof what !== "function") {
            return what.getRandomKey(arguments);
        } else {
            return Randomizer.getRandomKey(what.apply(this, arguments));
        }
    };
    //Get random element value of what if supported
    Randomizer.getRandomElement = function(what) {
        if ((!what) || (["undefined", "number", "boolean"].indexOf(typeof what) >= 0)) {
            //unsupported
        } else if (typeof what !== "function") {
            return what.getRandomElement(arguments);
        } else {
            return Randomizer.getRandomElement(what.apply(this, arguments)); 
        }
    };
}
```

This is how I initialize it

```
Randomizer();
```

Usage example

```
function lorem(b, a) {
    return a.substring(1);
}
Randomizer.getRandomElement(lorem, "abcde");
```

My question is as follows: How can I modify `Randomizer.getRandomKey` and `Randomizer.getRandomElement` so that I can avoid defining a `b` parameter in `lorem` which essentially is the `lorem` object itself at the `getRandomElement` call? Can I do something with the `arguments` object before calling `apply` to get rid of its very first element and pass the arguments after that?

Comment: Don't ever assign to prototypes inside a function. Do it once at most. And for native prototypes, best don't do it at all.

Comment: @Bergi, this function was meant to be called once at most. And I explicitly want to enable these randomization functions for any objects, arrays or functions.

Comment: Then don't put it in a function if you call it only once anyway. If you want to do for code structuring reasons, put the code in a module or IEFE.

Comment: @Bergi, this code is a simplification of the idea to not have to delve with unnecessary complications.

Comment: Yes, there is something you could do to `arguments` (e.g. `slice.call(arguments, 1)`), but why do it so complicated at all? Why would the user call `getRandomElement(lorem, "abcde")` instead of simply `getRandomElement(lorem("abcde"))`? Keep your API simple, don't overload it.

Comment: @Bergi, because it might be undefined, for example.

Comment: OK, this looks like a really confusing desing. What _is_ the end goal here? To be able to get any random property off any object? I don't think you really need to modify the prototypes of everything to do that. The whole redefining function signatures to fit with functionality they should not even know about is a really good tip that this take is a bad plan.

Comment: @Bergi, you are right in stating that arguments = Array.prototype.slice.call(1); at the start of Randomizer.getRandomKey and Randomizer.getRandomElement, respectively solves the issue. If you convert this into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Vld, the goal is to be able to get randomly any key and any value. The ability to do that generally. Actually, you will be able to call foo.getRandomElement if you know foo is a set. I believe that is pretty neat.

Comment: Again, why not `getRandomElement(foo)`? Presumably, you still need to call it if you're not sure if `foo` is not set. What if `foo` is set but it's not an object?

Comment: getRandomElement(foo) is possible, but I consider it to be less elegant, objects with possible states are more elegant. I might want to include a history there to see what were the results or what were randomized, for isntance. In that case a stateless function is not as helpful. This code is both more readable, provides support to any kind of object, provides freedom and if you add state to it, then it will be easier to read as well.

Comment: And if you initialize some members of that getRandomElement function, then you do the same, but your code will be less readable.

Comment: @Bergi, a function might return another function and so on...

Comment: Do not use `<< 0` to truncate array indices, because they can be higher than 2³¹-1. Use `Math.floor` or `>>> 0`

Comment: @LajosArpad: I see, but still this is a very confusing API. Finding the fixpoint of a function has nothing to do with getting random elements, if a user wants that he should call two separate methods.

Comment: @Oriol, thanks for pointing that out. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I do something with the `arguments` object before calling `apply` to get rid of its very first element and pass the arguments after that?

Yes, [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) does that:

```
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
….apply(this, slice.call(arguments, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `Array.prototype.slice` is using ES6 rest parameters:

```
Function.prototype.getRandomKey = function(ignoreFirstArg, ...args) {
  var result = this.apply(this, args);
  // ...
};
```